# Criteria on $f$ such that $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & f(t)\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\mathbb Z^2$ is equidistributed on the circle (periodic orbit)

Tags: nt.number-theory, homogeneous-spaces

Consider $\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & t \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\mathbb Z^2 \right)_{t\in \mathbb R} \cong S^1$. Let $\mu$ denote the rotation invariant Haar measure $m$ on this orbit. I wonder if there are any criteria on what kind of real function $f$ could make $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & f(t) \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\mathbb Z^2$ equidistributed on this circle (compact periodic orbit). Namely, for any continuous $F$ defined on this compact periodic orbit, we have

$$\lim_{T\to \infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T F\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & f(t) \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\mathbb Z^2 \right) dt= 
\int_{S^1} F(x)dm(x).$$

Ideally, I wish to find something close to the Fejér's theorem in the discrete case as in [Boshernitzan's notes](https://math.rice.edu/%7Emichael/teaching/426_Spr14/FejerThm.pdf).

Also, (I hope) these criteria should at least be able to determine the equidistribution for basic functions like $f(t):=t^{\alpha}$.

Comment: Are you interested in some discrete orbit? That question is not really interesting for the continuous case. For $t^{\alpha}$, $\alpha<1$, one does the trivial change of variable, ending with the integral $\frac{1}{T}\int_{s=0}^{T^{\alpha}}f(s)/s^{1-1/\alpha}ds$. Truncating to the end, one sees that the Jacobian is almost constant...